# Command npm.cmd install tns-template-hello-world-ng@3.4.3 --silent --save-exact --save failed with exit code 4294963238

Tags: nativescript

I am having issue creating a new NativeScript app. I have uninstalled Node, NativeScript and reinstalled with no luck. I am having the same issue with NativeScript Sidekick. I am not sure what cause it happen but the last thing I did on my environment was upgraded node to v8. Below are versions of tools running on my computer:

Windows 10
Node v8.10.0
npm 5.6.0
Typescript 2.7.1

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you have the complete NativeScript toolchain installed ?

Comment: @jowansebastian, thanks for the quick response. Yes I did. It just started to work after upgrading npm from version 5.6.0 to version 5.7.1. I guess it has something to do with the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it has to do with version compatibility; however, after upgrading npm (npm i -g npm) to version 5.7.1, I was able to create new NativeScript app. Seems to be too easy ...